# Is there a list of what information different airlines track about their flights?

Tags: air-traffic-control, radio-communications, airline-operations

It has been suggested in the media and in some answers here that airlines vary in the information they track about the status of their flights. Is there a publicly available resource that lists what information different airlines have about the location and status of their flights? For example, could a British Airways flight over the Atlantic or the middle of the Pacific have "vanished" in the same way that the Malaysian flight over the Gulf of Thailand?

Comment: You'd really need to ask each airline to find out what they track - but [this question about ACARS may be of interest to you as well](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/2278/)

Comment: I don't think such a list exists, why would all airlines share that informations?

Comment: @DeltaLima: If it were mandated to do so.

Comment: The only thing you'll find in the regs are the requirement that an the operator be able to locate, track and communicate each airplane it operates, for FAA ops anyway.  See this A http://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/2158/258 for more details on that.

Answer (score 2):

There is no particular list that provided by airlines company about their flights because it can be misused, but several statuses are provided:

(from http://www.flightstats.com/go/AirportTracker/airportTracker.do#1)

> Geographic Coverage - FlightStats provides definitive information for approximately 99.5% of U.S. flights, and better than 86% of flights worldwide.
>
> Completeness - FlightStats queries multiple sources to create a record for each flight enabling us to offer a broader range of information (for example, gate information).
>
> Accuracy - We have invested heavily in the areas of parsing, interpretation and error checking and developed the logic that enables handling of difficult issues such as cancellations, diversions and changing schedules.
>
> Codeshare Support - Our codeshare logic enables us to deliver flight information for both the operating and the marketing carriers, filling what is often a major gap in coverage.
>
> Real-time data sources include:
>
> - FAA ASDI Data Feed
> - European Data Feed
> - GDS (Sabre, Amadeus, Apollo, Galileo)
> - Direct Airport / Airline Data Feeds
>
> Batch data sources include:
>
> - Innovata Schedules
> - TSA Security Wait Times
> - Security Information
> - Health Information
> - Consular Information